# OpenFL and Haxe invalid call when running test projects

Tags: haxe, openfl

I've installed Haxe and OpenFL. I created a sample project:

```
openfl create PiratePig
cd PiratePig
```

when I run:

```
openfl test flash
```

I get the following error:

```
/usr/lib/haxe/std/haxe/macro/Context.hx:209: characters 9-30 : Invalid call
/home/tomto/haxelib/openfl/4,6,0/openfl/_internal/utils/ExtraParams.hx:13: characters 7-32 : Called from
--macro:1: character 0 : Called from
Aborted
```

The same error when I run `openfl test neko`

I get a different error for html5

```
openfl test html5
```

gives me

```
chmod: changing permissions of '/home/tomto/haxelib/lime/3,6,2/templates

/bin/webify-linux64': Operation not permitted
Error: Cannot copy to "Export/html5/release/bin/fonts/FreebooterUpdated.eot", is the file in use?
```

Any help getting this working would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you use the Linux install script for Haxe and Neko?

http://www.openfl.org/builds/haxe/haxe-3.2.1-linux-installer.tar.gz

Perhaps you have a bad install, or too new of a version?